# scala - argument appear only once, but can not be simplified to underscore

Tags: scala, arguments, simplify

in one of a simple experimental function I wrote

```
  def check[T](xs: Seq[T])(pred: T => Boolean): Boolean = xs.forall { x =>
    try {
      pred(x)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => false
    }
  }
```

I just want to see whether it can be simplified to

```
  def check[T](xs: Seq[T])(pred: T => Boolean): Boolean = xs.forall {
    try {
      pred(_)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => false
    }
  }
```

And if there is no `try - catch block`, it can be done as below

```
def check[T](xs: Seq[T])(pred: T => Boolean): Boolean = xs.forall {
    pred(_)
}
```

I am a little confused why the `try-catch` block make the argument explicit

Answer (score 1):

By the rules for underscores,

```
try {
  pred(_)
} catch {
  case e: Exception => false
}
```

means

```
try {
  x => pred(x)
} catch {
  case e: Exception => false
}
```

So the types of `try` and `catch` branches don't match. And creating the `x => pred(x)` lambda certainly won't throw an exception (unless you run out of memory).

Answer (score 0):

```
  def check[T](xs: Seq[T])(pred: T => Boolean): Boolean = xs.forall {
    try {
      pred(_)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => _ => false
    }
  }
```

will compile. so that the exception handler return type conforms to the forall method, according to spec 6.22.